# How to reshape a multiindex dataframe using pandas stack/melt

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

*I'm editing this to hopefully make it clearer. I am trying to utilize combination of stack and melt to turn this sample dataframe into the below desired output.

Using pandas I load in the excel table below with the end goal of making it tidy and long.

```
 df=pd.read('myfile.xlsx)
  df1= df.stack(level=1)
   df2=df1.melt(col_level =1)
```

Sample dataframe

|  | Good customer service |  |  |  | Fresh ingredients |  |  |  | Lots of seating |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Papa johns | Segment Avg |  |  | Papa johns | Segment Avg |  |  | Papa Johns | Segment Avg |  |
| 12/1/2019 | 70 | 88 |  | 12/1/2019 | 2.2 | 5.5 |  | 12/1/2019 | 5.2 | 8.8 |  |
| 12/2/2019 | 50 | 78 |  | 12/2/2019 | 6.8 | 4.4 |  | 12/2/2019 | 5.3 | 7.8 |  |
| 12/3/2019 | 60 | 77 |  | 12/3/2019 | 8.9 | 2.3 |  | 12/3/2019 | 6.3 | 5.6 |  |
| 12/4/2019 | 30 | 76 |  | 12/4/2019 | 7.3 | 7.3 |  | 12/4/2019 | 7.9 | 4.6 |  |

Here is the end result I'm looking for

| Date | Restaurant | Question | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/1/2019 | PapaJohns | Good customer service | 70 |
| 12/2/2019 | PapaJohns | Good customer service | 50 |
| 12/3/2019 | PapaJohns | Good customer service | 60 |
| 12/4/2019 | PapaJohns | Good customer service | 30 |
| 12/4/2019 | PapaJohns | Fresh ingredients | 2.2 |
| 12/4/2019 | PapaJohns | Fresh ingredients | 6.8 |
| 12/4/2019 | PapaJohns | Fresh ingredients | 8.9 |
| 12/4/2019 | PapaJohns | Fresh ingredients | 7.3 |

Comment: can you provide the code to create your sample?

Comment: I cannot unfortunately, the tables are exactly how it appears however.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following is how your excel file looks like:

[image]

Below are the steps how I would approach it using Pandas:

1. Read the file but skip the first two rows and remove the empty columns
2. Convert the DF into a multi-index DF
3. Melt and concatenate the DF using a `for loop`

```py
# Step 1
df = pd.read_excel("raw_data.xlsx", skiprows=2, header=None)
df.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True)


# Step 2(a): Create the multi-index column name
col_name = np.array(['date', 'Papa Johns', 'Segment Avg'])
category = ['Good Customer Service', 'Fresh Ingredients', 'Lots of Seating']
outer = [cat for cat in category for _ in range(3)]
inner = [col for _ in range(3) for col in col_name]


# Step 2(b): Change the DF into Multi-index
df.columns = [outer, inner]
print(df)

 Good Customer Service                        Fresh Ingredients             \
                   date Papa Johns Segment Avg              date Papa Johns   
0            2019-01-12         70          88        2019-01-12        2.2   
1            2019-02-12         50          78        2019-02-12        6.8   
2            2019-03-12         60          77        2019-03-12        8.9   
3            2019-04-12         30          76        2019-04-12        7.3   

              Lots of Seating                         
  Segment Avg            date Papa Johns Segment Avg  
0         5.5      2019-01-12        5.2         8.8  
1         4.4      2019-02-12        5.3         7.8  
2         2.3      2019-03-12        6.3         5.6  
3         7.3      2019-04-12        7.9         4.6


# Step 3
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'question', 'restaurant', 'score']) #Empty DF

for cat in category:
    temp_df = df.melt(id_vars=[(cat, 'date')],
                      value_vars=[(cat, 'Papa Johns')])
    temp_df.columns = ['date', 'question', 'restaurant', 'score']
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, temp_df])
    
print(final_df)

        date               question  restaurant score
0 2019-01-12  Good Customer Service  Papa Johns    70
1 2019-02-12  Good Customer Service  Papa Johns    50
2 2019-03-12  Good Customer Service  Papa Johns    60
3 2019-04-12  Good Customer Service  Papa Johns    30
0 2019-01-12      Fresh Ingredients  Papa Johns   2.2
1 2019-02-12      Fresh Ingredients  Papa Johns   6.8
2 2019-03-12      Fresh Ingredients  Papa Johns   8.9
3 2019-04-12      Fresh Ingredients  Papa Johns   7.3
0 2019-01-12        Lots of Seating  Papa Johns   5.2
1 2019-02-12        Lots of Seating  Papa Johns   5.3
2 2019-03-12        Lots of Seating  Papa Johns   6.3
3 2019-04-12        Lots of Seating  Papa Johns   7.9
```

Comment: Based on my question your response is the correct one, I will mark it so - I appreciate it.
I should have provided a much larger sample as their are about 30 different restaurants (Papajohns, Applebee's etc..) - so it's a bit more complex but I think I can build it out from here. Thanks!